# Smooth Scroll on a Web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently on my site (with Bootstrap) when a user clicks on an anchor with a link to the same page, I use the following jquery to make it scroll to the link, rather than jump:

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#target').offset().top}, 1000);
```

It works, but, I've seen some sites that use an animation that starts off slower and then speeds up as it scrolls and almost has a little bounce at the end.  It's very smooth/slick.  I'm looking to achieve something similar.

Anyone know of other ways to animate scrolling via links?  I'd prefer to avoid jquery plugins if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Probably just the `ease` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add easing to the animate method

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#target').offset().top}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce' });
```

*untested

Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Examples here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/quick-tip-add-easing-to-your-animations/

Answer (score 1):

The default easing of jQuery is `swing` and the only vanilla option is `linear`.

While you said you'd prefer not to use plugins, easy option would be including jQueryUI easings into the project. [It offers tons of options](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), look into the easings page and choose the one you prefer if `swing` doesn't satisfy (or make your own!). jQueryUI's Effects core weights in at 13kb's.